# Calculating voltage through unknown resistor

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current

[image]

I'm asked to get the voltage Ix and Vx, as you can see in the image, the voltage is on an unknown resistor, through loop analysis I got that Ix should be equal to 1. by KVL( Kirchhoff's Voltage Law) I had
$$5(Ix-6)+1(Ix)=0$$
although, I'm not quite sure if Ix and the 10A current source interact in this equation. so that is why I'm asking this.

For node analysis, please use this image (I'm not sure about N5 being a node btw)
[image]

Comment: No, your loop equation is incorrect. You can't assume that the voltage across a current source is zero. Since you are given so many current values I suggest that you start by using KCL. See how many unmarked currents you can determine. Then use Ohm's Law to calculate voltages across resistors.

Comment: rorod8, I'd suggest you first observe that you already know the voltage at \$N_3\$. Do you see why? And yes, you can consider \$N_4=0\:\text{V}\$, arbitrarily, and also don't need to solve for it. Now, you can also trivially solve for \$N_1\$ because you know both currents that sum and must pass through the 5 Ohm resistor.

Comment: @jonk I dont really know why, is it (v3-v4)/2 =4? And then since v4 =0 that yields v3=8V, right?

Comment: @rorod8 Do you see the \$4\:\text{A}\$ current on your diagram that goes through the \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor to ground? What's the voltage drop across that resistor? That tells you the value of \$N_3\$, right? Plus, you know that there is \$4\:\text{A}\$ going to ground through the \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor, plus there is another \$10\:\text{A}\$ exiting \$N_3\$ towards the right, so there must be the sum of these two flowing through the \$5\:\Omega\$ resistor, right? So then you know the voltage drop across that resistor and therefore also know the value of \$N_1\$, yes?

Comment: @rorod8 And now that you know the voltage for \$N_1\$, you also know that there is \$6\:\text{A}\$ coming into that node and now you know the current that is flowing out through the \$5\:\Omega\$ resistor (going south) and therefore you know the remaining current that must be flowing through the \$1\:\Omega\$ resistor (and its associated voltage drop.) So that means you also know the voltage at \$N_2\$ and also \$I_x\$. Do you see that this problem is actually pretty easy to do?

Comment: @rorod8 Just follow [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HGj4.png). You should be able to see why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsbYPW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using KCL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Using KVL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, we can solve for the unknowns.

---

Using your values we get:

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{6 == I3 + I4, I4 == 10 + I5, I6 == 10 + I3, 6 == I5 + I6, 
   I3 == (V1 - V3)/1, I4 == (V1 - V2)/5, I5 == V2/2, 
   I6 == (V3 - V4)/R4, I6 == V4/3}, {I3, I4, I5, I6, V1, V2, V3, V4}]]
```

Which gives:

```
{{I3 -> -((2 (4 + 5 R4))/(11 + R4)), I4 -> (74 + 16 R4)/(11 + R4), 
  I5 -> (6 (-6 + R4))/(11 + R4), I6 -> 102/(11 + R4), 
  V1 -> 92 - 714/(11 + R4), V2 -> (12 (-6 + R4))/(11 + R4), 
  V3 -> (102 (3 + R4))/(11 + R4), V4 -> 306/(11 + R4)}}
```

Now, when we know that \$\text{I}_5=4\space\text{A}\$, we get:

$$\text{I}_5=\frac{6\left(\text{R}_4-6\right)}{11+\text{R}_4}=4\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{R}_4=40\space\Omega\tag3$$

So:

$$\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4=\frac{102\left(3+40\right)}{11+40}-\frac{306}{11+40}=80\space\text{V}\tag4$$

Comment: Ty, I'll try to solve it my own way, but this way I will know if I'm doing right !!!